# Solr/Lucene Similarity class for short texts

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

If I have two documents with a field "name" indexed and the values:

- Doc 1: Manfred Müller
- Doc 2: Manfred Maximilian Müller

and I search for "Müller" on a Solr-Instance with two shards/replicas sometimes Doc 1 is higher scored than doc 2 and sometimes the other way around.
Which similarity class ranks reliable doc 1 higher than doc 2 (shorter = better)?

Query:

```
rows=100&fl=*,score&q=_query_:"{!complexphrase+df%3Dname}Müller"+OR+_query_:"{!complexphrase+df%3Dname_exakt}Müller"&fq=(quelle:GP)&sort=score+DESC
```

Fields:

```
<field name="name" type="komplexes_textfeld" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name_exakt" type="einfaches_textfeld" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="name_exakt"/>
```

RequestHandler:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="qf">name_exakt^3 name^2</str>
```

FieldTypes:

```
    <fieldType name="einfaches_textfeld" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer>
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-chars.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> 
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <!-- <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/> -->
          </analyzer>
          
          <similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BM25Similarity" />
        </fieldType>

<fieldType name="komplexes_textfeld" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-chars.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> 
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/> 
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" preserveOriginal="true"/>
        </analyzer> 
        
        <analyzer type="query"> 
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-chars.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> 
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/> 
        </analyzer> 
        
        <similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BM25Similarity" />
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/

Comment: I read that article yet and tested it but the result was the same for BM25.